# A React component suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified

Tags: reactjs

I just started working on this new React app.

It was using `<Suspense />` element in the component but I removed it. Then application is crashed with above error.

Is there any easy fix without know too much about `<Suspense />` ?

[image]

Comment: Could you post your code? However from just the error it's likely you haven't supplied anything to the `fallback` parameter. I'd suggest [reading up on the `<Suspense>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#suspense) component again and then modifying your code.

Comment: You might still be lazy importing the component. Remove it and do a normal import

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In order to fix this without putting `Suspense` back in, you would need to get rid of usages of [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#suspense).

Comment: pefectly solved my problem, but i wanna know why we cant use lazyload in suspense?

Comment: Perfect ! Could you please explain why we can't use lazy load in suspense?

Comment: @SatelBill You **can** use lazy load in Suspense. The question was trying to use lazy load **without** suspense which results in an error.

Comment: Why this guy takes lots of upvotes eventhought not answer any question

Comment: @sayinmehmet47 What was your question? Because this guy has clarified if you do not wish to use `<Suspense >` in your react code, additionally to removing the `<Suspense >` components, you also need to **replace** lazy load import statements(for example `const component = React.lazy(() => import("./Component"));`) **with** `import Component from "./Component";`

Answer (score 88):

You have 2 options:

1. Without Using suspense, you can configure that i18n.js like this:

   ```
   i18n
     .use(XHR)
     .use(LanguageDetector)
     .init({
       react: { 
         useSuspense: false //   <---- this will do the magic
       }
   });
   ```
2. Using Suspense, for example:

   ```js
   <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading... </div>}>
         <App />
   </Suspense>
   ```

Comment: I would prefer the first option. I had very bad sideeffects using the second option, since the suspense is defined not only for the i18n-translations.

Answer (score 13):

I know it's not exactly @IshanPatel's problem but what can cause this error message is if you use a hook like useTranslation() directly inside of the function holding `<Suspense />`. The solution is to move that code simply into a separate function and have the hook there (see screenshot).

This came up first on Google and I guess someone could waste a long time on finding a fix so I wanted to share it as comment.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Removing `React.lazy` is not a good idea. Since if your application grows it will take too much time to load the home page.

For react-router **v6+** we have the following:

```
<Route path="about" element={
  <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
    <About />
  </React.Suspense>
} />
```

Comment: Whew, alright. This seems to make the error gone when using react-router v6! ;-) At first I was being "lazy" by just wrapping the whole `<Routes>` with `<Suspense>` as shown in the docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting), i.e. `<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}><Routes>...</Routes></Suspense>` but doing it this way ain't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

One error we are easy to make:

```
// Error: In the fallback component, don't use i18n!
// <Suspense fallback={<div>{t('loading')}... </div>}>

// This is correct
<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading... </div>}>
  <App />
</Suspense>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, dont forget about `fallback` prop in `Suspense` component - it wont work without it.

Comment: OP mentioned that they removed the `<Suspense />` component

Comment: There is no <Suspense /> usage  in that case